# WPF. Prevent checkbox inside button from firing click event

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button with a checkbox inside in WPF. I want to be able to check the checkbox **without  firing the click** event of the button.

My problem is that, currently, the click event is fired whether I press the checkbox itself or its label, behavior I don't want. I only want to raise the click event if I press somewhere in the red zone.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this?

This is my code by now:

*Style for the checkbox:*

```
<Style x:Key="FilledCheckBox" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"> 
                <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Width="15"
                                Height="15"
                                CornerRadius="1"
                                BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Gray"/>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>
                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

*Style for the button (with the checkbox inside):*

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCornerButtonWithCheck" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="280" ShadowDepth="2" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.2" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="15" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              TextElement.FontWeight="SemiBold">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>

                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource FilledCheckBox}"></CheckBox>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Gold" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF33962B"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

*The button in the template:*

```
<Button Name="deleteButton" Style="{StaticResource RoundCornerButtonWithCheck}" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:Resources.Delete}, Converter={StaticResource CharacterCasingConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Red" Foreground="White" Margin="80,0,80,30" Click="DeleteClick"></Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent this?

You can't really prevent the built-in `Button` control itself from handling the click without cancelling the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event but you can implement the event handler to ignore clicks on the `CheckBox`:

```
private void SaveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.OriginalSource is CheckBox))
    {
        //handle click outside the CheckBox...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check if the OriginalSource is checkbox and set the `e.Handled` to true would that stop the Command from triggering?

Comment: @XAMlMAX: I am not sure if I understand your question. My sample code will only execute the code inside the if-case when the surrounding part of the CheckBox is clicked.